# How do I change the image?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to change the image when I click the button, but it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? I think there are something to do with the declaration
`val afterEatingImage:ImageView="R.drawable.after_cookie"`
and I tried = (R.drawable.after_cookie), R.drawable.after_cookie, after_cookie
Maybe I should not use Val for an image but I don't know what to use. So you can see this is a basic question and I am a beginner so pls help.

```
   fun eating(view: View?) {
       val afterEatingText:String="I am so full!!"
       displayMessage(afterEatingText)
       val afterEatingImage:ImageView="R.drawable.after_cookie"
       displayImage(afterEatingImage)
   }
   private fun displayMessage(message: String) {
       val afterEatingText = findViewById<View>(R.id.before_eating) as TextView
       afterEatingText.text = message
   }
   private fun displayImage(image: ImageView){
       val afterEatingImage: findViewById<View>(R.id.before_cookie) as ImageView
       afterEatingImage.setImageResource(image)
   }
}
```

The id of my ImageView is android:id="@+id/before_cookie"
The names of 2 imagefiles are before_cookie and after_cookie.

Red errors are as follows.
[image]

Another way to do this:

```
    fun eatCookie(view: View?) {
        // Find a reference to the ImageView in the layout. Change the image.
        val imageView = findViewById<View>(R.id.before_eating) as ImageView
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.after_cookie)

        // Find a reference to the TextView in the layout. Change the text.
        val textView = findViewById<View>(R.id.before_eating) as TextView
        textView.text = "I'm so full"
    }
```

The crash result after I click the button.
[image]

Message from Logcat

```
05-17 12:22:11.216 3029-3029/com.example.afterclicking E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.afterclicking, PID: 3029
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method eating(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:447)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:405)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

If I use `val textView = findViewById<View>(R.id.before_eating)`
then red alert appears.
If I use `val textView = findViewById<View>(R.id.before_eating) as TextView` then it will be fine, Why is that?
[image]

Comment: `afterEatingImage.setImageResource=image`  isn't correct syntax, replace it with `afterEatingImage.setImageResource(image)`

Comment: Thank for quick response. I changed that but there are several other errors.

Comment: I think you defined an `onClick` in your XML that is not available in kotlin code

Comment: This what I defined on my XML `android:onClick="eating"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is assigning the **String** *R.drawable.after_cookie* to your ImageView *afterEatingImage*. You pass this ImageView to your method and try to assign it as the image resource.

What you should do is the following

1. Pass the integer *R.drawable.after_cookie* to your method
2. Assign this parameter to your ImageView

This will become something like this

```
fun eating(view: View?) {
    val afterEatingText:String="I am so full!!"
    displayMessage(afterEatingText)
    displayImage(R.drawable.after_cookie)    //Change this
}

private fun displayMessage(message: String) {
    val afterEatingText = findViewById<View>(R.id.before_eating) as TextView
    afterEatingText.text = message
}

private fun displayImage(imageResource: Int) {   //Change this
    val afterEatingImage: ImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.before_cookie)
    afterEatingImage.setImageResource(imageResource)
}
```

*Note: I am assuming this is all done in your activity. In case you are doing this in your fragment, you need a reference of your view to find your ImageView*

Comment: Your answer is very clear. (1) so I should put the location `R.drawable.after_cookie` into `displayImage()` why is that? (2) I have tried another ways, pls refer the above question. Everytime I click the button, it crashes. (3) Why can't I  use `findViewById<View>(R.id.before_cookie) as ImageView` ? (4) I have to add `as ImageView` after your code `ImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.before_cookie)` otherwies   `Type mismatch:iferred type is View! but ImageView! was expected` but you already specify `ImageView=` upfront, why is `as ImageView` necessary?

Comment: Here are the answers to your questions: (1): You need to assign a resource drawable to an image, which is why we are passing the resource id to said method. (2) It crashes because it is trying to find the method named *eating* whereas you have named it *eatCookie*. (3) You can use it if you want. (4) I'm not entirely sure why this is happening. It should automatically cast to the type specified.

Comment: (2) fun eating(){ } and fun eatCookie(){ } are 2 different ways of doing this. They will not co-exist in my codes so they are not the reason of crashing.  (3) Every time I use `findViewById<View>(R.id.before_cookie) as ImageView` it crashes, do you know why? (5) Would you please see the 2nd way in my question of achieving this? Every time I use this set of codes, it crashes. This should work since I copies from https://gist.github.com/udacityandroid/dbc83e6d49dd1164d2b5 why does it crash every time?

Comment: I appreciate your time in answering my question. Since you have spent time, you must think my question have some value. Would you please up vote this question? This question will benefit others in the future as well.